# Print number of entries with mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I'm converting a mongo collection to a CSV using mongo export.  For one of the fields, I'd like to export the number of entries in that field instead of the entries themselves.  Any clues as to how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: A sample document would help here.  Like what is the data type of the field that you want to get the count of?  This may not be possible with mongoexport but without a sample document I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: The more I think about this, it is probably impossible.  I don't know of any "projection" operators that would get you the size of anything and I don't think you can call arbitrary javascript through mongoexport.  Maybe you need to look into Aggregation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ and set up some CRON or something to run an aggregation periodically, do the size/length calculation there, and mongoexport the collection directly.

Comment: You can't do this sort of data transformation with `mongoexport`, however it should be straightforward to write your own CSV export script which produces the expected results.